# Minimal investement problem

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment

```
    uint256 public max_contribution = 50 ether; 
    uint256 public min_contribution = 0.1 ether; 
function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public payable returns (bool success) {
    require(msg.value >= min_contribution);
    require(msg.value <= max_contribution);
    balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
    balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
    return true;
}
```

using this to set the minimal ETH investement, still receiving tokens when sending 0.1> amount of ETH. Testing on the testnet. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share an etherscan link to the testnet transaction?

Comment: Yes, sure https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xa2a4df6e6cde22fafd7255f3f16965e5928e7072053976252b6ca262b30befa5

Comment: Looks like logic from this source doesn't correspond deployed contract. Could you verify contract source to be sure that it has the same logic?

Comment: Yes, I agree with Dmytro Zarezenko. You should verify contract source deployed in Ropsten

Comment: 0xb1a89c746ecec28bfdf7f06f44b603bf9c035be8 new contract adress, with verified code. Still the same problem https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x8006101c803006b15b3f0852e4e59d9f2a909c8441578edc5fc3babcc842fb70